# Interface eth0 not configured

Tags: ubuntu, networking, router, static-ip-address

I'm trying to setup a static ip address. Here's my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# primary network interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.88
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 127.0.1.1
```

Apparently, my machine does not have eth0 at all. I've looked around and everyone says to configure the above file with eth0. Are there any other ways to set a static ip address using these devices?

```
$ ifconfig -a
eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 1c:1b:0d:0a:86:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xdf400000-df420000  

enp82s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9b71:b459:c8d8:4bc5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1c:1b:0d:0a:85:fe  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3712  bytes 2691239 (2.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1501  bytes 157372 (157.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf200000-df21ffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 25268  bytes 1537593 (1.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25268  bytes 1537593 (1.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp83s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e4:b3:18:8c:05:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just replace `eth0` with one of the other interfaces.

For example:

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.88
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 127.0.1.1
```

Comment: Could I use lo? According to netstat -i, lo's MTU is higher.

Comment: No you cannot. `lo` is your loopback interface.

Comment: Ok. Does it matter which one I choose? I don't know the difference between these interfaces.

Comment: Just tried switching to eno1 instead off eth0. When I try sudo ifdown eno1, I get: ifdown: interface eno1 not configured.

Comment: All of these interfaces represent separate physical network interfaces on your machine. Are you are trying to change the IP address of `enp82s0`, which currently has an IP address of `192.168.1.7` to `192.168.1.88`? If so, please pick `enp82s0`

Comment: I just tried enp82s0 and that didn't work. ifconfig still shows 192.168.1.7.

Comment: `ifdown enp82s0 && ifup enp82s0`

Comment: That gives me: if down: failed to open lockfile /run/network/if state.enp82s0: Permission denied

Comment: Adding sudo with that gives me: ifdown: interface enp82s0 not configured

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50602/cant-ifdown-eth0-main-interface for your issue with ifdown

Comment: my /run/network/ifstate already contains lo=lo and enp82s0=enp82s0, but I still get the aforementioned issues.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to reboot my system. Thanks for the help.